# Any difference between 'further' and 'pursue'?

Tags: word-meaning

I have finished a fundamental course in cooking at a high school, 
and I am going to study an advanced course in cooking at a university.

I ask this question because I am accustomed to using "further" as a verb. When I told my friends that "I want to further my study of cooking at a university,
 they asked me why I wanted to "pursue a bachelor's degree" on hearing my plan, and this made me wonder if I had misunderstood the usage of "further".

Given that situation, are these two sentences different in meaning?
1. I want to further my study of cooking at a university.
2. I want to pursue a bachelor's degree in cooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They express very different notions.

- To *further your study* or *further your knowledge* means that you want to extend your study or knowledge into new, unspecified domains: you are moving in a particular direction but have no particular end in sight.
- To *pursue a degree* means that you want to arrive at a specific state, which might be understood as either mastery of specific body of knowledge or achieving the formal accreditation: you are moving toward a particular goal.

In your particular situation they may amount practically to pretty much the same thing; the difference lies in how you portray it.

Comment: Exactly. Put another way, everyone who is pursuing a degree is also furthering their education, but not everyone who is furthering their education is pursuing a degree.